# Embedding text file into HTML

Tags: html, django

I'd like to embed the contents of a plain text file into my HTML page. The problem is that the code I have written doesn't embed it -- it starts the download automatically.

I'd like to simply embed it into the page -- and then later give someone the option to edit it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px; overflow: auto;"><object type="text/html" data="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{item.content}}" style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:1%;"></object></div>
```

Note: `{{item.content}}` inserts a .txt file.

Comment: Why are you putting it in an object rather than just dumping it inside the `div`? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I don't know Django but if I was trying to do something similar in Rails, I wouldn't bother with the object.

Comment: When you say just dump it into the `div` -- does that mean I turn `object` into something else? like a `<p>`, or ???

Comment: what is item.content? is it actually a file (uploaded to your database in a models.FileField)?

Comment: Yes, it's the path to the text file (ex: `/path/to/file/file.txt`). And yes it's a `models.FileField`

Comment: @user1328021 I just didn't understand the need for the `object` in the first place - I would just put everything directly in the `div` unless there was something particular about your content but seeing as it's a simple text file, I would think this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to get the contents of the text file into a string or something before you pass it to your template -

```
def your_view(request):
    #...
    f = item.content.open(mode='r')
    str = f.read()
    return render(request, {'file_content': str})
```

Then access the contents in your template with `{{ file_content }}`.